JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application
In program.cs I have the following:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var key = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"];
    var keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    options.SaveToken = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes),
        //define which claim requires to check
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        //,ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ////store the value in appsettings.json
        //ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]
    };
});
...
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

I have an AuthenticationManager which I pass inject into my auth controller with the following method:
public string Authenticate(UserCredential user)
{
    var key = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key");
    var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
         {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName),
            new Claim("AdminID", user.AdminID.ToString())
        }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                              new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes),
                              SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
        Issuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        Audience = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}

Finally in the AuthController, I have the following code, user lookup omitted for brevity:
var token = _jwtTokenManager.Authenticate(userCredential);
                    
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
cookieOptions.Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7);
cookieOptions.Domain = Request.Host.Value;
cookieOptions.Path = "/";
Response.Cookies.Append("jwt", token, cookieOptions);

return Ok(new { token = token });

The login page doesn't actually do much, I'm sending the request off via Ajax as follows:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnLogin_click() {
        var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Auth/Authenticate',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Successfully received Data ');
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Failed to receive the Data');
                console.log('Failed ');
            }
        })
    }
</script>

I feel like I'm almost there... I'm running into a few issues:
I'm not receiving the cookie on the front end, when I try to navigate to a page I'm still getting the unauthorized page redirection (401)...
I feel like one step I need to take is to intercept requests on the front end in order to add the bearer token to any requests. Not sure if this is the way to go for ASP.NET Core 8 MVC, was definitely the way to go with Angular.
End result I need the login process to provide authentication which can be used on both Ajax requests as well as asp postbacks.
Kind of feeling like saving this token to a cookie using Javascript methodology then intercepting requests to the server to append the bearer token may be the quick and dirty of it.
Unless somebody knows a way through this hell

Please kindly check the network trace, you can open the developer tools and check the network tabs, check if the Authorization header exist or not in that request.

Y/es, this is exactly what I did.  In the browser I checked the network trace and found that the Set-Cookie header was not being processed because the domain did not match the url..  I found while testing locally that it is necessary to remove the Port from the domain...  fix was to replace "Request.Host.Value" with "Request.Host.Host"

Make sure your cookie is configured correctly to be sent back to the client. You may need to set the SameSite attribute properly. For example, you can set SameSite to None and ensure Secure is set to true if you're using HTTPS
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
    Domain = Request.Host.Value,
    Path = "/",
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = true
};
Response.Cookies.Append("jwt", token, cookieOptions);

Your backend should be properly configured to validate the token sent in the Authorization header. This part of your code looks good but ensure that the audience and issuer are set correctly
```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var key = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"];
    var keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyBytes),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"]
    };
//To validate the JWT token from the cookie in each request.
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var token = context.Request.Cookies["jwt"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                context.Token = token;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };

});

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

If your frontend and backend are on different domains, ensure CORS is configured to allow credentials
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
});

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");


To send cookie in every request to server using Ajax in your case you should make following changes to make sure cookie included in every request this will happen automatically if xhrFields.withCredentials to true
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnLogin_click() {
        var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Auth/Authenticate',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: data,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true // Ensure cookies are sent with the request
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Successfully received Data');
                console.log(result);
           
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Failed to receive the Data');
                console.log('Failed');
            }
        });
    }

    // Ensure cookies are sent with AJAX requests
    $(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    });
</script>

Verify the cookie is being set correctly by inspecting it in the browser's developer tools (under Application > Cookies). Check the network requests to ensure the cookie is sent with each request.

Thank you for mentioning xhrFields.withCredentials...  Although that wasn't what solved the issue, it's good to know on future ajax requests...  I actually found the issue was because I was using cookieOptions.Domain = Request.Host.Value; which won't work on localhost as it includes the port number...  I've modified this to: cookieOptions.Domain = Request.Host.Host; and it has resolved the issue

Thank you for mentioning xhrFields.withCredentials...  Although that wasn't what solved the issue, it's good to know on future ajax requests...  I actually found the issue was because I was using cookieOptions.Domain = Request.Host.Value; which won't work on localhost as it includes the port number...  I've modified this to: cookieOptions.Domain = Request.Host.Host; and it has resolved the issue
